# Running Total Column in Table Structure

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to create a table which can store my expenses and I plan to connect it to Power BI which will help me creating a dashboard. What I want to achieve is a column in table structure which will contain my account balance. The idea is to insert the opening balance with the first row in this column and then have that column calculate the value automatically with next inserts.

For example, say I insert first row with some transaction and opening balance as $100. The next row has an expense of $10, so this column will have $100-$10 = $90 calculated automatically. If the next insert is an incoming transaction of $5, this column will have $90+$5 = $95.

I know this is easily achievable by window functions in SELECT clause, but window functions cannot be used in table definitions.

I have tried creating a table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE Transactions 
(
    TranID int PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1),
    [Date] date,
    Category varchar(50),
    Remarks varchar(500),
    Debit Decimal(10, 2) DEFAULT 0,
    Credit Decimal(10, 2) DEFAULT 0,
    Balance AS (LAG(Balance, 1) OVER (ORDER BY TranID) + Credit + Debit)
)
```

Comment: Put the logic in a *view* and use that for reporting.

Comment: @Stu Thanks for the suggestion. Creating a view is my last option. I just wanted to know if what I want is achievable or not. If it isn't, I am creating a view.

Comment: A computed column in a table can only refer to the current row. Hacky workarounds exist using scalar functions but with drawbacks, the better solution is a view, why is this a last option? It's the obvious choice.

Answer (score -2):

Why don't you create a trigger instead.

```
-- Create the Transactions table
CREATE TABLE Transactions (
    TranID int primary key identity(1,1),
    [Date] date,
    Category varchar(50),
    Remarks varchar(500),
    Debit Decimal(10,2) Default 0,
    Credit Decimal(10,2) Default 0,
    Balance Decimal(10,2) Default 0
);

-- Create the trigger
CREATE TRIGGER UpdateBalance
ON Transactions
AFTER INSERT
AS
BEGIN
    UPDATE t
    SET t.Balance = ISNULL((SELECT TOP 1 Balance FROM Transactions WHERE TranID < i.TranID ORDER BY TranID DESC), 0) + i.Credit - i.Debit
    FROM Transactions t
    INNER JOIN inserted i ON t.TranID = i.TranID;
END;
```

Comment: This is not a good idea for many reasons; If a row gets updated the data is immediately inconsistent.

Comment: Yeah after you mentioned my answer is not the ideal one and would work when the data is not being changed once inserted.